# Unable to start Service via JobScheduler in Android Oreo

Tags: android, service, android-8.0-oreo, android-jobscheduler

I created an app that uses firebase services. Whenever there's a change in value, a notification is generated. So for this,my service must be continuously running,else there will be no notification. I did created and successfully get it running in pre-oreo Android OS. My service runs perfectly even after clearing from recents and force closing but not in Oreo.
Upon googling i came to know about automatic start of service in Oreo is prohibited. We need JobScheduler for this purpose.

This is my JobService class-

```
import android.app.job.JobParameters;
import android.app.job.JobService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.Log;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public class Serviceo extends JobService {
    private JobParameters params;
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        this.params = jobParameters;
        Log.d("HEYY","i'm here");

        Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationService.class);
        getApplicationContext().startService(service);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

PS- Extending JobService gave error that it needs min api=21, so i rectified it using **@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)**

And in my Service's `onDestroy` method, i declared my JobService like this-

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("EXIT", "ondestroy!");
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.mukesh.mu.RestarterBroadcastReceiver");
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    stoptimertask();

    Log.i("BRUHHH","hi");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Log.i("BRUHHH","hi2");
        jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(1, new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
            Serviceo.class.getName()));

    //run job service after every 5 seconds
    builder.setPeriodic(5000);
    jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());

    }
```

This method is executed but service ain't getting started. I can see in logcat "hi2" executed.
I also declared it in manifest

```
  <service
        android:name="com.mukesh.mu.Serviceoreo"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        />
```

Everything work's fine and normal in pre-Oreo builds via Intent and broadcast but not working in Oreo.

Comment: class name `Serviceo` is different than `Serviceoreo` declared in manifest.

Comment: A `JobService` is Not a Visible Process . And you can not start a `Service` if you do not have a `Visible` process . Read https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Alternatives of Job Service- Firebase JobDispatcher